# QEMU VM reboots host upon running

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am trying to run `virt-install` on Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 in order to install a QEMU VM from a qcow2 image. Running `virt-install`, I get no errors.

```
$ virt-install ...

starting install...
...
virsh --connect qemu:///system start nameofvm
```

However, when I run that command, Ubuntu (host) simply instantly crashes (no error screens or anything) and then reboots

Any help would be absolutely fantastic! Thanks, and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Best to create the VM after the restart. Basically the machine in not in a running state while being kickstarted. You shouldn't rely on things such as services to be running during a kickstart. Use "InitialSetup" to run your virt-install . https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/InitialSetup

InitialSetup may not be available in Ubuntu although it doesn't mention it as a missing feature.https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch04s06

Pre-seed is a more comprehensive automated install system for Ubuntu so you may find something similar there.

Comment: I was wondering if that was some of the issues... Do you think that I could just set up a script to run once upon power on and then remove itself after that?

Comment: Just updated the question. The issue is broader than kickstart now, as I decided to test using normal ubuntu-server and manually typing in commands

Comment: Try using a crash kernel to get some logs https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe

Comment: I tried using the crash kernel with the instruction here: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html and I got nothing showing up in `/var/crash` after running `virsh start vmname`